# android Camera2 preview to record switch issue

Tags: android, camera2

From this google [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) example, we can see it start preview mode firstly, then if user click record button, we will close preview session and create a record session to start record. After record finished, we will close record session and start a preview session again.

But it seems we can see a video flash (maybe a black frame) at the beginning of recorded video.I guess such flash maybe caused by the record session frame has some delay, so record video has some black frames.

How can we resolve such issue? Is it possible to just use the same session rather than close and recreate again? Current example use

```
mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
```

for preview session and use:

```
mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
```

for record session.what's the difference?